# iOS13 navigation bar back bar button item tint color

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller, swift5, backbarbuttonitem

I have a navigation bar embedded Search Controller. When Search Controller is dismissed, navigation back bar button item is reverting to default color(blue) only in iOS13.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Here:
[Gif](https://imgur.com/gallery/xmqX3p6)

Comment: No, never tried. I've test it with iOS 13.1. But I should fix this issue for the iOS13.1 and iOS13.0 users.

Comment: OK but the problem is you do not explain how the back bar button item got its tint color. There is a new iOS 13 way to do that. Are you using the new way, or are you just setting the tint color of the navigation bar? That isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced this problem too.

I have placed a custom button instead of system back button.
It worked for me.

> You should put it before push to viewController. If you have two or
>   more viewControllers, you should put it at first.

```
    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    backItem.title = "Back" 
    backItem.tintColor = .red
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
```